# Collisions of milk

Tags: collision

I am studying collisions of two thin sheets of whole milk with each other versus two thin sheets of skim milk with each other.  The coefficient of restitution of whole milk is significantly higher than that of skim milk.  I'm thinking that upon collision, the whole milk stores some of the energy dissipated and then rapidly releases it again thus giving a higher after collision velocity than skim milk would have under the exact same conditions.  I have theory that well describes the collisions for water and skim milk.  Now, I'm thinking that I need to add a term to the theory to account for this storage of energy in the whole milk.  So modeling it as a spring for example.  I'm wondering what I would use as the "spring" constant for whole milk. I'm guessing that it is the fat particles in whole milk that store this energy; skim milk has a much lower fat content that would seem to be negligible based on the results of experiments.